# Unknown inline modifier Java regex

Tags: java, regex

i am parsing some text files in which the escape character is `?` - There is also 4 escaped characters : `+ ' : ?` . I think the clear escaping was working fine ( might be wrong tho ) until i added spring batch. Now when i try to launch the parsing of the file, this is failing and i don't get why.
Here is the error :

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 6
(\?)(?|:|\+|')
```

And there is the code

```
private String regex = "(\\?)(?|:|\\+|')";
private String clearEscaping(String s){
    return s.replaceAll(regex, "$2");
}
```

Can someone explain me why this is not working ? And how should i fix the issue ? Is there any more efficient way to do the escape clearing ?

Comment: Problem is here `(?|` (an unescaped `?`) it should be replaced with `([?:+'])`

Comment: You are using `(?|...)`  that is a branch reset group not supported in Java regex. Also, `"(\\?)(?|:|\\+|')";` should be rewritten as `"(\\\\?)([?:+'])"`. Or, `"\\\\?([?:+'])"` and then `replaceAll(regex, "$1")`.

Comment: @anubhava you are right !

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot for your response you saved me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to anubhava to point out that my regex was wrong in the 1st place & giving me the fix.
Thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew, for the complete solution & make it clear !

=> I changed my regex to `"(\\\\?)([?:+'])"`